# How to extract coordinates that belong to a zip code or borough in R or Python?

Tags: python, r, mapping

I have a list of locations (with no addresses, just latitudes and longitudes separated in two different columns) in New York City. 
If I want to extract the locations in Manhattan, how would I do it in R or Python?

The method I am using is to use function `revgeocode` in `ggmap` to pull out the full address. For example:

```
revgeocode(c(-73.99596, 40.75936))
```

would give:

```
'561 10th Ave, New York, NY 10036, USA'
```

Then I would use `grep` to see if the address has one of the zip codes of Manhattan:

```
grep("10036|10001|10011|10018|10019|10020|10036|10029|10035|10010|10016|10017|10022|10012|10013|10014", loc, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE, value = FALSE,
 fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE, invert = FALSE)
```

which returns `1` as a positive.

I realize it would probably not the best approach for this situation. Moreover, `revgeocode` uses Google Maps API which limits the use of queries per day. So I hope if there is any other better approach to this problem that I haven't thought of or come across of. For example, I am thinking if is there is a rule that:

```
#pseudo code
if latitude in range(X1, X2) and longitude in range(Y1, Y2):
    borough = "Manhattan"
```

I hope someone can fill over my lack of geocoding and geography knowledge in this situation.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi, it's the first time I asked a question here, so I didn't really know to write a question properly. I have edited my question, added my approach and what I want to know. Hope you can help!